# Getting the stack trace of a console message

Tags: javascript, browser, console.log

Sometimes I see stray log statements when I load up my application, and I don't remember how the log statement was called. Is there a way to find the stack trace of a console log message from the Chrome developer tools?

Right now, I wrap console.log with a function that prints the stack trace:

```
console.log = (function () {
  var oldLog = console.log.bind(console);

  return function () {
    try { throw new Error(); } catch (e) {
      oldLog(
        e.stack.split('\n')
          .slice(2)
          .map((line) => line.trim().replace('at', 'from'))
          .join('\n')
      );  
    }   

    oldLog.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  };  
}());
```

This will print the stack trace in addition to the log message. For this to be useful, I have to insert this code just before any of my code runs. Is there a way to find out this information from just the console, without having to add this wrap?

I primarily use Chrome developer tools, but I'd be interested if this was possible in any other browser.

Comment: When you perform a console.log from code (not the console), you can look all the way to the right side of the console to see the location (and even click it to open it.) That of course doesn't work if you override it with your own function because then it will simply point to your replacement console.log instead of the one used directly in the code.

Comment: ah, right. what about the stack trace?

Comment: Those only exist for errors, so you won't be able to get that with a console.log. Have you tried console.trace?

Comment: console.trace(); or console.trace(value) .. prints value and trace ..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`console.trace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console)? It is available in Chrome and Firefox. For your use-case, you could alias log to trace.

That said, I usually wrap logger statements in a custom logger function that itself wraps whatever I need to use, but which can be programmatically disabled in production to prevent leaking logs.

EDIT:

There aren't currently any chrome://flags that would let you set that behaviour, but you could do this before your console gets invoked (such as at the top of your minified js): `console.log=console.trace;`

Which will have this effect, (example in Chrome Canary's console):

```
> console.log("Hello, Robz");
VM929:2 Hello, Robz
undefined
> console.log = console.trace;
function trace() { [native code] }
> console.log("Hello, Robz");
   VM935:2 Hello, Robz
   VM935:2 (anonymous function)
   VM468:777 InjectedScript._evaluateOn
   VM468:710 InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap
   VM468:626 InjectedScript.evaluate
```

Comment: oh that's cool. console.trace effectively does the same as the wrapper I wrote. by 'alias' do you mean doing what I'm doing with my wrapper? I would like to do this without having to modify my code at all--can I alias it as a browser setting?

Comment: You wrapper is elegant, but the builtin is faster. I'll update my answer with specifics.

Comment: You can just as easily wrap this in an `if()` looking for your deployment environment: if production, `console.log=function(){};` if you wanted to take a small, weak step toward mitigating your log leakage. That in turn can still be overridden, so the best is to use a preprocessor (grunt?) to look for `console`s and strip them.

Answer (score 0):

Basically. To show the source of a logging-message was a very bad idea. It leads you to write logging messages that neither belongs to the code nor can be localized without a stack-trace.

How do you work in a Team with it?

```
hey, i got a `ohoh!`-logging in file abc.js in line 3487!
```

To understand the problem by inspecting the call-stack means: Hey i do not need a text-message, i do not need a message what exactly is going on, just where.

Comment: Indeed. I'm actually trying to debug log statements that a team member added without putting context in the message :)